# How to return everything in an output except something specific

Tags: python, python-requests

Is there any way that i can get an output to only display the IP addresses that are not the one the user input at the start of the script? The start of my code is below.

```
def get_asset_group_criteria(group_number):
    asset_group_number = str(group_number)
    asset_group_path = "/api/3/asset_groups/" + asset_group_number + "/search_criteria"
    url5 = server + asset_group_path
    response = requests.request("GET", url5, headers=headers, verify=False)
    data = response.json()
    print(data)

x = input("What is the asset group id?: ")
get_asset_group_criteria(x)
```

The output of the print command returns the following:

```
{'match': 'any', 'filters': [{'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': '192.168.1.0'}, {'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': '192.168.1.1'}]}
```

To further elaborate on what i am trying to do based on this output:

I would like for the script to ask the user what IP address will not be included in the output. Then the script will go through and respond with everything that isn't that IP. Once this is done i would like to use PUT to update the search criteria in the program im using this for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way that i can get an output to only display the IP addresses that are not the one the user input at the start of the script?

Yes, all you need is to filter the array of `data['filters']` from the response, excluding a desired IP. Check the snippet below:

```py
def get_asset_group_criteria(group_number):
    asset_group_number = str(group_number)
    asset_group_path = "/api/3/asset_groups/" + asset_group_number + "/search_criteria"
    url5 = server + asset_group_path
    response = requests.request("GET", url5, headers=headers, verify=False)
    data = response.json()
    return data

def put_asset_group_criteria(group_number, data):
    asset_group_number = str(group_number)
    asset_group_path = "/api/3/asset_groups/" + asset_group_number + "/search_criteria"
    url5 = server + asset_group_path
    response = requests.request("PUT", url5, json=data, headers=headers, verify=False)
    return response

x = input("What is the asset group id?: ")
ip = input("What IP should not be included?: ")
data = get_asset_group_criteria(x)
data['filters'] = [filter for filter in data['filters'] if filter['value'] != exclude_ip]
print(data)
resp = put_asset_group_criteria(x, data)
print(resp)
```

What I've done is to update the array of `data['filters']` by generating a new one, copying every element except the ones with value equal to `exclude_ip` argument.

The output should be: `{'match': 'any', 'filters': [{'field': 'ip-address', 'operator': 'is', 'value': '192.168.1.0'}]}` if `192.168.1.1` is informed.

The PUT request is very similar to the GET using your current interface, all you need to change is the name of the method, from `"GET"` to `"PUT"`, and pass a `json` argument to the request, containing your data. Check [the docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.request).

Comment: how would i then do a put request using the new output without the desired ip?

Comment: @pythonscrub What is the endpoint for put? Is it the same? I've updated the code, it now does a PUT request.

Comment: yeah the endpoint is the same. i will try that now and see if it works

Comment: it says "NameError: name 'group_number' is not defined" but i realized you named it group_member on accident so i fixed it. The error now is that the put request responds with a 415 error

Comment: @pythonscrub Can you post the error message also? Perhaps it requires JSON format, I'll update the code.

Comment: i added in json format as you did and it worked. thank you for your help!

Comment: @pythonscrub Does your local code have multiple `x = input("What is the asset group id?: ")`